# Login via URL in IBM Cognos Analytics

Tags: authentication, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I would need an URL for Login in IBM Cognos Analytics - so that you dont need to type in the user and the password (should be contained in the URL). This should directly link to an existing dashboard.
I tried the instructions of this IBM Page https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=settings-defining-authentication-parameters-login-urls - but I always get the error message, AAA-AUT-0011 Invalid Namespace.

I am using IBM Cognos Analytics with Watson 11.2.4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the URL you are using being sure to mask out the UID and PWD section.  It should have the format of http://yourserver:yourport/bi?CAMNamespace=myNamespace&CAMUsername=myUser&CAMPassword=myPassword.

You'll also want to check the NamespaceID defined in the cogstartup.xml on the Content Manager server for the security provider you are using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.